# Google Directions API (Transit mode) returns only one alternative route per request

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I have built an small application which calls the Google Directions API in Transit mode. It works - nevertheless **it returns only one possible route**, so it shows no alternatives. Usually I expect 3-4 options to choose from.

Example:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=bieberstrasse,+dusseldorf&destination=norf,+neuss&sensor=false&mode=transit&departure_time=1399399424

The returned JSON structure has the expected "routes" array, but this array always has only one element. I have tried it with addresses in Brazil and Germany - it doesn't matter the country, I only get one single route.

Did I miss some parameter? Could someone help me with it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want alternative routes, specify [the request parameter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#RequestParameters) `alternatives=true`:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?alternatives=true&origin=bieberstrasse,+dusseldorf&destination=norf,+neuss&sensor=false&mode=transit&departure_time=1399399424