# Google Maps json output for all routes

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

my question is about google maps json output. 
i've here a start address and end address :

[Google Maps Link](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/M%C3%BCnchen+Hauptbahnhof,+Bayerstra%C3%9Fe+10A,+80335+M%C3%BCnchen,+Deutschland/48.1498983,11.5366509/@48.1451849,11.537781,16z/data=!4m10!4m9!1m5!1m1!1s0x479e75f93d8ab293:0xd5fe7137da4467b7!2m2!1d11.557766!2d48.140458!1m0!3e3!5i1)

And at the following link, i display the result as json format :

[Google Maps Json Format](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=M%C3%BCnchen%20Hauptbahnhof,%20Bayerstra%C3%9Fe%2010A,%2080335%20M%C3%BCnchen,%20Deutschland&destination=Landshuter%20Allee%2033,%2080637%20M%C3%BCnchen,%20Deutschland&sensor=false&departure_time=1343605500&mode=transit)

It displays only one legs(route), but from start address to end address i've 4 routes. 
My question is, how can i display all routes in my json output?

Can you help me? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Directions API (Transit mode) returns only one alternative route per request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23502060/google-directions-api-transit-mode-returns-only-one-alternative-route-per-requ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a parameter `alternatives=true` to the URL:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=M%C3%BCnchen%20Hauptbahnhof,%20Bayerstra%C3%9Fe%2010A,%2080335%20M%C3%BCnchen,%20Deutschland&destination=Landshuter%20Allee%2033,%2080637%20M%C3%BCnchen,%20Deutschland&sensor=false&departure_time=1343605500&mode=transit&alternatives=true